# Tools for workshopping celestial body orbits

Tags: planets, space, space-colonization, worldbuilding-resources

I am working on a scifi setting that mostly takes place among the moonlets and boulders of a gas giant's ring system.  The humans living in this world travel slowly, in primitive spacecraft, between celestial bodies with negligible gravity.  At the moment the biggest gap in my outlining of this setting is the travel time between different destinations.  I am looking for a tool that will help me make rough estimates for answering this question:  **What is the closest approach between two given moonlets, and how often are these moonlets within that approach?**

- My budget for this tool is around $40 but I would be willing to pay more in some cases.
- I have some javascript and python coding experience but very little background in using libraries and APIs, so something that's ready to use out of the box is much preferred.
- I have not taken a math class since highschool.  Calculus is a distant memory - basic algebra is the extent of my mathematical aptitude.
- Kerbal Space Program won't cut it.  I need to be able to play around with the volume, mass, and orbit of different celestial bodies to obtain the desired travel distances for narrative purposes.

Comment: Have you looked in detail at the add-on tools ("mods") available for Kerbal Space Program?  A combination of one of the various system editors and Principia should do what you need very nicely.

Comment: Not sure, but besides universe sandbox, look at space engine as well, but not sure if it has all the functionality you need. There is a some nasa tool for precise orbit calcilations, seeking optimal orbits and such, but do not recall its name and I didn't managed to make it to work, learning curve was quite steep and it was buggy on linux or what - was quite some time ago, I hope someone recognises the thing for you to name it.

Answer (score 3):

For this sort of simulation, on a reasonable budget, I recommend Universe Sandbox. It is ready-to-use out of the box for simulating orbital mechanics, and allows you to tweak the masses and volumes of the bodies in question. It has no easy tool for analyzing the travel time between bodies, but I believe there are a fair few Hohmann transfer/departure-window plotting tools that will take you from orbital elements to travel times in one very short step.

Answer (score 1):

If your story is set in our real-world Solar System, then Wolfram Alpha may help with your calculations, in combination with some source of information on celestial bodies you are interested in. It will also show and explain (in the Pro version) relevant formulas.